MariaDB - Is it safe to delete a large temporary file?
I am running MariaDB on a Windows Server 2022 Standard and I am running out of disk space on the system disk.
I have found a file named ib534F.tmp with 65 GB related to MariaDB in the path:
C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\MariaDB_PROJECT\AppData\Local\Temp

According to Windows, this file was last edited on 04.10.2022, but I'm not sure if that's true.

Is it safe to delete this file?
What can happen in the worst case?

This file was created by query that doesn't fit into memory. You have to find out which query is a culprit and kill it. The temporary file will be deleted automatically.
As far as creation datetime is pretty outdated I suspect this is residues of some ancient failure. If no query associated with it you can try to delete it manually. But it would be safer to stop mariadb before deletion.
